# I got syntax error in update statement.Run-time error: 3144 I am using the following code

Tags: ms-access, vba

```vb
Dim strMyTable As String 
Dim strMyField As String 
Dim strMyCombo As Boolean 
Dim strSQL As String  
strMyTable = "ItemDetails"  '(or whatever the true names are...) 
strMyField = "Chk" 
strMyCombo = False  
strSQL = "UPDATE " & strMyTable _ & "SET " & strMyField & "=" & strMyCombo & ";"          
Application.CurrentDb.Execute strSQL  
End Sub
```

Comment: If you add debug.print strSQL after assigning it you will see that your query string is badly formed. You are missing the space before the word SET. (BTW your Hungarian notation "strMyCombo" is misleading for a Boolean!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim strMyTable As String 
Dim strMyField As String 
Dim strMyCombo As String
Dim strSQL As String  

strMyTable = "ItemDetails"  '(or whatever the true names are...) 
strMyField = "Chk" 
strMyCombo = "False"  
strSQL = "UPDATE " & strMyTable & " SET " & strMyField & "=" & strMyCombo & ";"          
Application.CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```